# java mongo db regular expression non-letter character

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

This is my code:

```
for (String term : segment.terms) {         
            DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("linkTitles", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(term));
            or.add(clause1);
}
DBObject mongoQuery = new BasicDBObject("$and", or);        
DBCursor cursor = pageLinks.find(mongoQuery);
```

The problem with this is that if for example the term is "obama", it wil lgive me objects that has linkTitles like "meprobamate". I want to give a regular expression that only gives me "obama" as a whole word in any situation like `" obama ", " obama." " obama, "`, etc.

In all of the cases "obama" might be between spaces or any punctuation, how can I say in java code for the mongo db regex to consider any punctuation letter or space around the term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b` word boundary to do this.. change your line to the following

```
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("linkTitles", 
                   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b"+term+"\\b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have text search enabled on your field, try to search them with the text search queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text.

```
Example: db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to wrap the `<term>` in the word boundary as below:

```
\\b<term>\\b

where
\b - is a word boundry
```

Comment: I said `Somehow` because the `<term>` may already contain some reqex notation i.e. `/obama/gi`