# OR Query mongodb from java with "like" and "line break" and "case insensitive" at the same time

Tags: java, mongodb, line-breaks, case-insensitive

This is sample of one document in my mongodb collection page_link_titles:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553b11f30b81511d64152416"),
    "id" : 36470831,
    "linkTitles" : [ 
        "Syrian civil war", 
        "Damascus", 
        "Geographic coordinate system", 
        "Bashar al-Assad", 
        "Al Jazeera English", 
        "Free Syrian Army", 
        ...

        "February 2012 Aleppo bombings", 
        "2012 Deir ez-Zor bombing", 
        "Aleppo University bombings"
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the documents that the text in their `linkTitles` contains a phrase like `'%term1%'` or `'%term2%'` or (so on). term1 and term2 must have a line break in both sides. For example looking into `"Syrian civil war"`. If `term1 = "war"` I want this document to be returned as the result of query, however if `term1 = "yria"` which is a part of a word in this document, it shouldn't be returned.

This is my java code:

```
for (String term : segment.terms) {
    DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("linkTitles",
            java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b"
                    + stprocess.singularize(term) + "\\b"));
    or.add(clause1);
}

DBObject mongoQuery = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
DBCursor cursor = pageLinks.find(mongoQuery);
```

In line: `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b"+ stprocess.singularize(term) + "\\b"));` I only assumed line break. I don't know how I should write the regex to consider all my conditions : [line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976711/java-mongo-db-regular-expression-non-letter-character), [case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query), [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using a text index? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#text-search that will handle plural and single terms and not match parts. It will also be much quicker than performing non anchored regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do a regular expression that achieves what you want. You can also use a single regular expression rather using `$or`.

I'm using the shell for a quick example and wanting to search for `boxer` or `cat`. First insert the test data:

```
db.test.drop()
db.test.insert([
{ "a" : "Boxer One" },
{ "a" : "A boxer dog" },
{ "a" : "A box shouldn't match" },
{ "a" : "should match BOXER" },
{ "a" : "wont match as this it the plural BOXERs" },
{ "a" : "also match on cat" }])
```

Using the following regular expression we can search for all our terms:

```
                                       
      /(^|\b)(boxer|cat)(\b|$)/i       
       +---+ +-------+  +---+         
          |       |        |           
          |       |        |           
   Start or space |       Space or end 
                  |                    
              Search terms
```

And do a find like so:

```
db.test.find({a: /(^|\b)(boxer|cat)(\b|$)/i})
```

That query will return the following results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de36"), "a" : "Boxer One" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de37"), "a" : "A boxer dog" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de39"), "a" : "should match BOXER" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de3b"), "a" : "also match on cat" }
```

In Java you might build this query up like so:

```
StringBuilder singularizedTerms = new StringBuilder();
for (String term : terms) {
    singularizedTerms.append("|").append(stprocess.singularize(term));
}
String regexPattern = format("(^|\\b)(%s)(\\b|$)", singularizedTerms.substring(1));
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regexPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Theres two problems with this approach.

1. It will be slow
   It can't use an index so will do a full scan of the collection, if you have 10 million documents it will check each one!
2. It won't match plurals
   For example it won't match the document containing "BOXERs" because our regular expression explicitly doesn't allow for partial matches!

[Text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) support this.  Using an index will make the operation faster as well as matching plural or single values, for example:

```
db.test.createIndex( { a: "text" } )
db.test.find({ $text: { $search: "boxer cat"}})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de3b"), "a" : "also match on cat" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de3a"), "a" : "wont match as this it the plural BOXERs" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de36"), "a" : "Boxer One" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de37"), "a" : "A boxer dog" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555f18eee7b6d1b7e622de39"), "a" : "should match BOXER" }
```

Comment: The text index you mentioned, I created that, but how should I use that in java?

Comment: By using `find` and the `$text` operator - see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/